# What are the pros and cons pertaining to "latex -> dvipdfm" versus "latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf"?

Tags: pdf, compiling

There is another option to produce PDF actually, i.e., using pdftex. But let's omit it in this topic.

I usually do "latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf" to get pdf output. My LaTeX input file contains eps graphics, pstricks codes, and plain text. I have not tried to use "latex -> dvipdfm".

What are the pros and cons pertaining to both options?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The pros of one tend to be cons of the other, so I'll just list features. What comes to mind straight away:

## dvips

- More widely used (I think); has larger range of support in packages that use its `\special`s features.
- The subsequent PostScript file can contain arbitrary PostScript code, which is a programming language; some packages require this feature to do subsequent processing on the output (e.g., `pstricks`, `psfrag`)

## dvipdfmx

- (successor to `dvipdfm`)
- Aims to be feature compatible with the PDF features that are accessibly though pdfTeX. Such as PDF annotation, file attachment, and so on.
- Started out at being better with multilingual/UTF8 processing for some of the Oriental-based TeX systems; I suspect it's required for some CJK packages but I don't know the details.
- `xdvipdfmx` is the fork that allows XeTeX to produce PDF output; while Mac OS X has `xdv2pdf`, on Windows/Linux there's no alternative.

Answer (score 6):

Using `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` works with `pstricks` , `beamer` and `powerdot` and gives you all the graphics features of `xypic`; using `latex`+`dvipdfm` does not. However the latter approach may give a much smaller file size.